# Can I merge one file|commit or I need to merge the whole files?

Tags: git

I have two different branches: `branch_1` and `branch_2`. I made a few changes in a file `index.php` at `branch_2` among other changes in other files and I commit them. Now I am working on `branch_1` and I need the changes I have made in `index.php` only. Is there any way to bring `index.php` from `branch_2` into `branch_1`? Be aware I don't need every change I have commited on `branch_2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you may find the answer at [this page](http://jasonrudolph.com/blog/2009/02/25/git-tip-how-to-merge-specific-files-from-another-branch/).
The long story short:

- Checkout the path from the branch you want to merge using

  `$ git checkout source_branch -- <paths>...`
- or merge hunks selectively

  `$ git checkout -p source_branch -- <paths>...`

  You can eventually use reset and then add with the option `-p`,

  `$ git reset <paths>...`
  `$ git add -p <paths>...`
- Commit changes

  `$ git commit -m "Pick several changes from index.php"`

Comment: Generally I suggest to keep commits as small as possible. This will allow you to move your changes using simple cherry-pick.

Comment: I have to learn about cherry-pick since I am not aware could you add an example using it? if it's possible on this scenario?

Comment: I think that calling `git cherry-pick {commit-hash} --no-commit` can be used to get all changes from the commit where changes to index.php were made. After that you can manually remove unnecessary modifications in code leaving just those that you want.

Comment: Ok, this will be a try for a crap project where I can loose all the work :p for now I will keep tied to your first answer but thx for the info

Comment: If you want to try something new that can be harmful for your project, simply create copy of directory in which the project is and play with this copy instead of project itself. Git will work the same for both situations and you will have a backup :)

Answer (score 1):

For the times where you need the change recorded in history as well as made in the source,

```
git checkout -b wip $(git merge-base branch1 branch2)
git checkout branch2 -- files to merge
git commit -m 'merge files to merge from branch2'
git checkout branch1
git merge wip
git checkout branch2
git merge wip
```

If there's going to be more work done on the files you're merging, this will clue git in so you don't get conflicts in later merges.